# How can i do segregate in array based on user input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of users and also i have dropdown and  to filter users.
when page load `SearchData` will be empty so ng-repeat will display all the data .when user enter subjectn we need to filter user data how can i do this

below i have added my code some body help me on this .

```js
var myApp = angular.module('sandbox', ['ngMaterial']);



myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

   

    $scope.subjects = [{
            "name": "tamil",
            "value": "TAM"
        },

        {
            "name": "english",
            "value": "ENG"
        },

        {
            "name": "science",
            "value": "SCI"
        }
    ]

    $scope.sclass = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']



});
```

```html
<div ng-app="sandbox">
   <div layout-gt-sm="row" layout="column" layout-margin>
      <main flex-md="60" flex-order-gt-sm="2">
         <div style="width:30%;" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    >
            <div ng-repeat="user in users">
               {{user.id}}{{user.userclass}}{{user.name}}
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick ES6 vanilla way would be (posting only filter function which is the main thing)

```
$scope.filterusers = function() {

  if (!$scope.filterData) return; // you don't init the filterData to {} so this will short when you press filter without touching anything

  var filterId = $scope.filterData.id
  var filterSubjects = $scope.filterData.subject;
  var filterClasses = $scope.filterData.class;

  $scope.filteredUsers = filterId ? $scope.users.filter(user => user.id == filterId) : $scope.users; // not === since you input string, you can solve this by making unput type number
  $scope.filteredUsers = filterSubjects && filterSubjects.length > 0 ? $scope.filteredUsers.filter(user => filterSubjects.includes(user.subject)) : $scope.filteredUsers;
  $scope.filteredUsers = filterClasses && filterClasses.length > 0 ? $scope.filteredUsers.filter(user => filterClasses.includes(user.userclass))  : $scope.filteredUsers;

 console.log($scope.filteredUsers)
}
```

When initializing the controller you can set:

```
$scope.filteredUsers = $scope.users;
```

To make sure you have the unfiltered list displayed:

You can now bind `$scope.filteredUsers` to view instead of `$scope.users`

You keep the `$scope.users`, so you always have the full set of data to filter from :)

In short, I have applied cascading filter:
If a certain filterData property is set it filters by it if not it returns previous filtered.
This way you can apply more filters and you always filter 1 by 1 property, it's easier to read and it skips filtering in case there is nothing set in a certain filter.

If you wanna go full AngularJS way with this you should use its approach described here (I don't like it because it is more code and more obscure on how it works):

[AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

EDIT: I made some assumptions from your naming - like `subject` should be `subjects` if its multiple possible etc, here is an updated answer and a working fiddle:

[fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/rbhgLp9y/15/)

Comment: Oh, those are multiple choices and I missed the index one. I will be improving upon your fiddle ;)

Comment: @komal Here you go :) In 1st answer I skipped some details (like that there is multiple choice in filters). Now it works for all filters even if some are not set. Which is important since your 1st filter (by id) negates all others, assuming id is unique for each student. Also, you can put that from filed to type = "number" to allow only numbers (or if you hate additional UI that comes with it, put a function with regex check that purifies all non numerisc from it)

Comment: I did in the end of the answer there is link to it. Here it is again: https://jsfiddle.net/rbhgLp9y/4/

I improved upon yours, see the number 4 in url :)

Comment: @komal You are right, this is due to the once initialized array when you deselect everything still stays an array, doesn't go away. Here is improved version fiddle on that link now and I have updated the code to be more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

If your are interested in a more generic way you should check my answer on this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250009/angular-6-multi-field-filter/53250531#53250531)

Comment: You realize he tagged AngularJS not Angular ?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith you realize my solution is independent of any framework?

Comment: I see, the name of the link put me off, my mistake.